# Save/load array of custom objects to plist Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, save, plist

The application is a simple to-do list so I've got a mutable array of custom objects.
Here's an interface of the custom class:

```
    @interface Task : NSObject 
    {
        NSString *name;
        BOOL completeness;
        int priority; 
    }
```

And I've got a dilemma. What to choose NSCoding or converting the Task into NSDictionary?
I mean which way is more efficient?

It's gonna be my first application. And at first i didn't have an idea that i have to save the data. Should i remake the model?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You may want to consider using an `NSInteger` type in place of the int for the priority value.

Comment: you mean it doesn't matter don't you?

Comment: i've replaced int with NSNumber

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSDictionary` or 2 `NSMutableArray`'s for name objects and priority objects, I didn't worked on `NSCoding` till now, so i don't no about that. 
I will suggest you to use `NSMutableArray`'s and corresponding 2 `plist` files for every Array. If u use `NSMutableArray`, This [Creating Multiple Plist files in document directory..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559639/creating-multiple-plist-files-in-document-directory) Link will helpful for you. All the best

Comment: thank you. but i decided to use NSCoding. i'll post the code later.